# Parse.com relationships and ACLs

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, relationship

Think of this question in a blog context, I'm using Post and Comment to represent our actual app.

We're trying to build an app using Parse.com, and want to display a list of Posts, with the number of Comments alongside. There seems to be 2 ways to do this, and one seems incredibly inefficient, but the other requires that all users have write access to the Post.

### Inefficient Way

Store a relation in each Comment referring to the Post, then run *1 query per displayed Post* to count the number of Comments:

```
var postsWithComments = [
  // {post: post, commentCount: 0}
];

(new Parse.Query(Post))
.find()
.then(function (posts) {
  posts.forEach(function (post) {
    (new Parse.Query(Comment))
    .equalTo('post', post)
    .count()
    .then(function(commentCount) {
      postsWithComments.push({
        post: post,
        commentCount: commentCount
      });
    });
  });
});
```

### Insecure Way

Store an array, pointer, or relation on Post, referring to each Comment that belongs to it. This allows quick and easy counting, as well as easy access via `Query.include()`. The problem is that *every user needs write access to Post* in order to add a Comment.

Is there another way to store or query this data that I'm missing? All I need is a collection of Posts with the count of Comments. The user can tap to see those Comments (at which point we can load the actual data in).

Edit to add:

### Manually-Maintained Way

Further googling has found people getting around this issue using Cloud Code to update a column on the parent object using an afterSave on the child object. Pseudo-code:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Comment", function(request, response) {
  var comment = request.object;

  var post = comment.get('post');

  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend('Comment'));
  query
    .equalTo('post', comment.get('post'))
    .count()
    .then(function(commentCount) {
      post
        .set('commentCount', commentCount)
        .save()
        .then(function() {
          response.success();
        }, function(error) {
          response.error(error);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: IMO, I thought the last manner which has a count column keep updated should workaround, other methods are all inefficient. And also note that it's better to use `increment` operation instead of `set` with a specific count.

Comment: Agree with eth3lbert. The manually maintained way is probably the most efficient in this situation (efficient in terms of not smashing the API limits). Also, in your "inefficient" way above, if you use a Relation you cannot use the `Query.include()` method. Relations are not supported with that method. To get around the issue about all users having write access to the post, you could have a restrictive ACL, but use the master key for updating the Post's comment count based on a new Comment being saved.

Comment: Thanks, both. I think the analogy falls apart a little when it comes to using increment(), as sometimes a change to a Comment will make it not count towards the total.